# Date is between two other dates

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I getValue() from a sheet with a date   calldate = 29/08/2021 09:30:00

I am getting two other dates from a form : fromdt and todt

I want to check if the calldate is between fromdt and todt

I tried

```
function onFormSumbit(e) {
  //Timestamp   1Name   1From Date  3.From Time 4To Date    5To Time    6Reason                     
  var name = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,2).getValue();
  var fromdt = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,3).getValue();
  var fromtime = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,4).getValue();
  var todt = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,5).getValue();
  var totime = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,6).getValue();
  var reason = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,7).getValue();
  if ( todt=="") {todt=fromdt} ;
  if ( fromtime=="") {fromtime=9}   ;
  if ( totime=="") {totime=19} ;
  var empss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxx"); // service calls 
  var sltsht = empss.getSheetByName("Slots");
  var vA =sltsht.getDataRange().getValues();//first column is a date with some time
  for (k=1;k<vA.length;k++){
     if (vA[k][3]==name && vA[k][0].getTime() >= fromdt.getTime() && vA[k][0].getTime() <= todt.getTime()){
//do something
}
}
```

I want to only compare the dates. I want to ignore the time.

The above code is not able to display the matching records.

Comment: How are you running the function? Also please add more details like some sample input data and the expected results.

Comment: Did you try to console log one of the xx.getTime()? Or better yet... the debugger?

Comment: You should learn how to use the event object.  You don't how to read the line in the spreadsheet with a function call because all those value are already in e.values or e.namedvalues

Comment: If you wish to compare them numerically try getting their values like this: `let fromdatevvalue = new Date(e.values[2]).valueOf();`  You can use valueOf() or getTime() to compare dates numerically.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the time zone in sheet and in script (by switching to legacy editor). Both are same.

const dateOnly = new Date(dateAndTime.toISOString().slice(0,10))

Did not work. It resulted in getting the data for the previous day.

Then I tried with

const fromdt = new Date(lvvals[0][1].setHours(0,0,0,0));

It worked perfectly.

Thanks

I'm giving below the final code

```
function test(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var lvvals = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(12,2 , 1, 7  ).getValues();
  //const fromdt = new Date(lvvals[0][1].toISOString().slice(0,10)); //returned the previous date
  const fromdt = new Date(lvvals[0][1].setHours(0,0,0,0)); // worked correctly
  if ( lvvals[0][3]=="") {lvvals[0][3]=lvvals[0][1]} ;
  //const todt = new Date(lvvals[0][3].toISOString().slice(0,10));
  const todt = new Date(lvvals[0][3].setHours(0,0,0,0));
  var empss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxx"); // service calls 
  var sltsht = empss.getSheetByName("Slots");
  var vA =sltsht.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (k=1;k<vA.length;k++){
     //sltdt = new Date(vA[k][0].toISOString().slice(0,10));
     sltdt = new Date(vA[k][0].setHours(0,0,0,0));
     if (vA[k][3]==lvvals[0][0] && sltdt.getTime() >= fromdt.getTime() && sltdt.getTime() <= todt.getTime()){
     // do something
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to get rid of time part, you can use

```
const dateOnly = new Date(dateAndTime.toISOString().slice(0,10))
```

and then compare getTime() values. Be careful with timezones, make sure that your script timezone (defined in appsscript.json) matches the spreadsheet timezone (defined in sheets menu **File>Settings**)

Comment: *toISOString* returns UTC values that are then parsed as local by the constructor. Far better to use *setHours*: `date.setHours(0,0,0,0)`. ;-)

Comment: Thanks @RobG. setHours worked. Actually I tried it earlier, but, failed. Now it is working

Answer (score 0):

If you need just to parse and compare the dates in this format the quick and dirty solution is here:

```js
// 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss' --> 'YYYYMMDD'
const parse_date = d => d.replace(/(\d\d)\/(\d\d)\/(\d+).+/, '$3$2$1')
const is_between = c => (c > fromdt) && (c < todt);

var fromdt   = parse_date('28/08/2021 09:30:00');
var todt     = parse_date('30/08/2021 09:30:02');

var calldate = parse_date('29/08/2021 09:30:01');
console.log(is_between(calldate)); // true

var calldate = parse_date('27/08/2021 09:35:01');
console.log(is_between(calldate)); // false
```

But the best practice is to use the [Data object](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/features/dates), consider time zones etc.